# PHP: Replace time string 00:00:00 to 00:00

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a huge string, this is an extract:

```
$str = "time1, 12:05:00, time2, 02:25:00, time3, 11:00:00";
```

I'd like to have this output since the seconds will always be 00:

```
time1, 12:05, time2, 02:25, time3, 11:00
```

This is my code so far:

```
$str = str_replace(':00', "", $str);
```

But it's not giving me the output I'm expecting (see the 11 alone)

```
time1, 12:05, time2, 02:25, time3, 11
```

How can I accomplish this in PHP?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://php.net/strpos http://php.net/str_replace

Comment: @KubaWyrostek Question updated, apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the real string you have to deal with, we can only give vague answers. Here's mine:

```
<?php
$str = 'time1, 12:05:00, time2, 02:25:00, time3, 11:00:00';
echo preg_replace('/(\d{2}:\d{2}):00/', '${1}', $str);
?>
```